# What are some words for sound coming from somewhere?

Tags: novel, dictionary

I am learning/ trying to write a novel but I'm facing this problem. Whenever sound comes from somewhere (for example, from behind a closed door), I don't know how to describe it. I just end up writing "came from behind the closed door." What are some better ways to write these?
Another example:

> Suddenly, a loud shriek came from behind the locked door.

Comment: Hi! Let's clarify, you have no issue with the type of the sound ("shriek"), but only with probable location ("behind the locked door")?

Comment: Yes. The sounds themselves don't matter. Its just how I present them. I can't good alternatives to sound coming from behind something or just somewhere.
I just don't want to flat out write "the shriek *came from behind the door*"

Comment: Oh yeah, one more thing. The place doesn't matter. Whether it be from behind somewhere or a tree. Basically, the character I'm following doesn't see the sound being made. Only hears it. And so, I have to write in that way. 
Sorry if I'm being confusing; I'm still getting used to all of this.

Comment: Are you looking for alternate ways to say the same sort of thing? i.e. "there was a shriek from beyond the door"; "she heard a shriek through the door", ".. from the other room". Or do you want some other way to localize the sound? "There was shriek. Everyone looked toward the door."

Comment: Both actually (leaning a little bit more toward the same sort of thing). Thanks for the examples. I'm baffled these didn't come to my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Color:

I don't think there is anything wrong with saying that a noise came from somewhere. But I'm guessing you mostly find this boring. Usually, the source of a noise is either clear or not significant.

- **Locate it by character action:** The characters hear a rattle, and move towards the source of the sound, attempting to open the door which stubbornly resists all attempts to open. The characters face the door as the demonic wail howls.
- **The Door is the source**: The door whispers softly, or reverberates with the loud pounding. The frame rattles and shakes, and the door trembles.
- **Colorful language:** The hum emanates from the direction of the door. The whisper seems to creep out from under the door. The bang travels through the door like it wasn't there. The door holds back the horrifying sound.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly, an eldritch shriek curdled the air. I whisked around, but the room was empty... unless there was someone on the other side of my bedroom door.

<><><>

My hands flew to my ears at the sound of a scream overhead. Bethany glanced over from her salad, concerned. "You okay, dude?"

"Yeah. Did you hear that?"

"Hear what?"

I don't answer her. My eyes are fixed skyward, but whatever made the noise is already long gone.

<><><>

The screaming follows me all day, belting out screeches at random times. Whether it's a hallucination or a ghost, I don't know, but it sure makes the school a whole lot more sinister.

<><><>

Here are just some descriptions I came up with. Sound can be described in more than one way: pitch, volume, tone, direction, distance, how resonant it is, context, how the protagonist reacts, and how others react, to name a few. Instead of focusing only on where the sound is, perhaps you can try making it interesting by adding other important details. (Similes and metaphors, too, if they're not cliched)

I'm just a 15 y/o writer myself and this might not be professional advice, it' just my own opinion - but I hope you found this helpful! Have fun writing :D

Comment: That's excellent advice! I'll try to implement these next time I'm writing. Thank you SO much.